# How can I read two different data types from binary file in C?

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct{
    int user_id;
    char username[100];
    char password[25];
} User;
int id = 10001;
User array[50];

...
```

And then the important part that's failing (writing and reading):

```
FILE *f = fopen("users.dat", "w");
User aux;
int j = 0;


for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
                fwrite(&array[i],sizeof(array[i]),1 , f);   
            }
            fwrite(&id, sizeof(id), 1, f);  
fclose(f);
f = fopen("users.dat,"r");
while(fread(&aux, sizeof(aux), 1, f)){
        array[j++] = aux;
    }
    fread(&id, sizeof(id),1 ,f);
```

Can someone explain me why this doesn't work? AKA why it's reading all the User but it doesn't read the id. I've tried having an int counting the number of users and only printing those but it didn't work as well.
Thanks for the help and i'll post more code if needed.

Comment: What's not working about it? What is written to the file?

Comment: Is this the actual code you are trying? You have opened one file `f` for reading. Which you then write to. Close between reading and reopening? Make sure you open for writing to begin with

Comment: Well, I manage to read all 50 Users but the reading of the int id returns 0 (not read).

Comment: The second `while` will read some of the id and get to the end of the file...

Comment: Nope @doctorlove, I edited a bit, in the original code I am opening and closing like I should.

Comment: @mch damn. let me edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second loop

```
while(fread(&aux, sizeof(aux), 1, f))
```

will read the id - moving to the end of the file, so the following read will fail.

If you save to the file how many user record to read back and loop for that number you can get it to work.

Comment: so, by order: 
1 - save array length
2 - save all users
3 - save id
right?

Comment: Indeed. Unless the 50 is always going to be 50.